# Redirect to a page along with a parameter on session timeout

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a page for example: www.samplepage.com/Index?id=1001, 
I then store this id in a session to use it throughout the solution. But when the session times out I need to redirect to the sample page (www.samplepage.com/Index?id=1001), I am using the OnActionExecuting ActionFilter method. But now I loose the id value as it is stored in a session. And the id changes based on certain conditions and I cannot hard code it.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
   HttpContext session = HttpContext.Current;
   if (HttpContext.Current.Session["EmployerId"] == null)
   {
       filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Index");
       return;
   }
   base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

How can I store id value and use it in the ActionFilter?

Comment: If session expires (it is gone) , you cannot read the session value. It is like trying to withdraw money when you do not have an account in the bank

Comment: Can't you just store the ID in a variable when the page is loaded and pass the ID to the redirect page via querystring when the page times out?

Comment: @IamBatman: I was planning to do that as last resort. Was thinking if there is a cleaner approach to do it.

Comment: I agree with IamBatman and Shyiu, You could play volleyball with some view data or hidden input. Is there a reason why you have to use session?

Comment: @BillRuhl: The Id is a vital piece, and I was trying not to use that in the query string.

Comment: pass it using a post instead of a get. The only other thing I can think of off the top of my head is add an employer id property to the user object. Assuming of course that users are required to login in order to use the app.

Comment: @BillRuhl: This app has no login page, and that's why I need to redirect to to a page along with the id. The id basically determines the data source in this project.

Answer (score 0):

The session timeout is a sliding timeout. Each time a request is received by the server from the client, the timeout is reset. The only way the session can expire is if the client has absolute no interaction with the server for more than the specified timeout. As a result, there's no way to redirect when the session expires, because that would first require a request from the client to issue the redirect (request-response: the server cannot respond unless it first receives a request, and a redirect is a type of response).

Furthermore, by the time the user attempts to make a new request after the session has expired, well the session has already expired. The id you're storing, therefore is also gone, so redirect or not, there's no way to reset the id as there's no record of what it actually was.

Personally, I'd recommend simply implementing a piece of long-polling AJAX that will have the effect of keeping the session continuously active as long as the page is open in the user's browser. You just need to hit the server at some point before the session expires, so if that's 20 minutes, send the AJAX request after 19 minutes and you're good for another 20. You could also simply set the timeout longer, such that maybe expiration won't be as much of an issue.

Short of that, you'll need to ensure that the links you generate include the id as part of the query string, and any forms include the id as a hidden field. That way, if the session ever expires, the id still exists *somewhere* in the request and you can simply set it in the session again.